# Animation effects not coming into play

Tags: javascript

I am new to Web Development.
Can anyone please tell me why my Javascript code is not showing any animation effects into the website. I am trying this from last 3 days and I am unable to get the solution.

Please help me in getting this issue solved.

```js
var v = document.getElementById("booking-form").validate({
  rules: {
    bf_totalGuests: {
      required: true
    },
    bf_date: {
      required: true
    },
    bf_time: {
      required: true
    },
    bf_hours: {
      required: true
    },
    bf_fullname: {
      required: true
    },
    bf_email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }

  },
  errorElement: "span",
  errorClass: "error",
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertBefore(element);
  }
});

document.getElementsByClassName("next-btn1").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("tab-pane").hide();
    document.getElementById("step2").fadeIn(1000);
    document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar-dots').removeClass('active');
    document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar-dots:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
  }
});
document.getElementsByClassName("next-btn2").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("tab-pane").hide();
    document.getElementById("step3").fadeIn(1000);
    document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar-dots').removeClass('active');
    document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar-dots:nth-child(3)').addClass('active');
  }
});

document.getElementsByClassName("submit-btn").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    document.getElementById("loader").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("booking-form").html("<h2>Your message was sent successfully. Thanks! We'll be in touch as soon as we can, which is usually like lightning (Unless we're sailing or eating tacos!).</h2>");
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300|Oswald');

/* Form fields */

#booking-form {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  max-width: 540px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

#booking-form ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#booking-form li {
  list-style: none;
}

#booking-form input,
#booking-form textarea,
#booking-form select {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 28px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgb(233, 233, 233);
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 35px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#booking-form select {
  background: url('https://seashineadventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/grey-chevron.png') no-repeat;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-size: 15px;
  background-position: 97% 50%;
}

#booking-form textarea {
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 15px 28px;
}

#booking-form input:focus,
#booking-form textarea:focus,
#booking-form select:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);
}

#booking-form label {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Buttons */

#booking-form .next-btn,
#booking-form .submit-btn {
  background: #82CCC8;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: oswald, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  min-width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#booking-form .next-btn:hover,
#booking-form .submit-btn:hover {
  background-color: #444b5d;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Progress Bar */

.progress-wrap {
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
}

.line-progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.line {
  height: 1px;
  width: 250px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.progress-wrap div ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 250px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: initial;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progressbar-dots {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: #949494 solid 4px;
  background: #333333;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #d4d4d4;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color: #d4d4d4;
  border: 0px solid rgb(217, 217, 217);
  background: rgb(217, 217, 217);
}

.progressbar-dots span {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 60px;
  /* width: 75px; */
  float: left;
  margin-left: -30px;
  display: none;
}

.progressbar-dots.active {
  color: #fff;
  border: 0px solid rgb(38, 163, 134);
  background: #82CCC8;
}


/*  Tab */

.tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-pane:first-child {
  display: block;
}


/* Error */

span.error {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "helvetica neue", arial, sans-serif;
  color: #D6041D;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./placeOrder.css">
  <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#" id="booking-form">

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="step1">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>How many guests in your group?</label>
            <div class="errorTxt"></div>
            <select name="bf_totalGuests" required>
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="More">More</option>
            </select>
          </li>
          <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
            <button class="next-btn next-btn1" type="button">Next</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="step2">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>Which date and time are you looking to book on?</label>
            <div class="errorTxt"></div>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="bf_date">
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>Which time of day?</label>
            <div class="errorTxt"></div>
            <select name="bf_time">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
              <option value="Midday">Midday</option>
              <option value="Late afternoon, ending with a sunset">Late afternoon, ending with a sunset
              </option>
            </select>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>How many hours would you like to charter for?</label>
            <div class="errorTxt"></div>
            <select name="bf_hours">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="Overnight (24 hours)">Overnight (24 hours)</option>
            </select>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button class="next-btn next-btn2" type="button">Next</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="step3">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>What is your first and last name?</label>
            <div class="errorTxt"></div>
            <input type="text" name="bf_fullname">
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>Which email address should we send your free estimate to?</label>
            <div class="errorTxt"></div>
            <input type="email" name="bf_email">
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>Do you have any questions or a message? (Optional)</label>
            <textarea name="bf_message"></textarea>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button class="submit-btn" type="submit">Request My Free Estimate</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="progress-wrap">
      <div class="line-progress-bar">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <ul class="checkout-bar">
          <li class="progressbar-dots active"><span>step 1</span></li>
          <li class="progressbar-dots"><span>step 2</span></li>
          <li class="progressbar-dots"><span>Final step</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="loader" style="display: none;">
      <img src="//d2erq0e4xljvr7.cloudfront.net/assets/img/ring.svg">
    </div>
  </form>
  <script src="./placeOrder.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have even included all the libraries, where am I getting wrong. please guide me

Comment: People aren't going to click on some random web link.  Edit the question and add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

We should add this just before the closing head tag.. This worked for me.

Comment: Yeah! I noticed that and changed accordingly, now it's working properly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: We just have to add the the two scripts mentioned above just below the closing head tag. and It'll run, its running on my machine

Answer (score 0):

You are using `JavaScript` selector and trying to use jQuery functions with those selectors.

You need to convert your selectors to jQuery:

```
$(".next-btn1").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    $(".tab-pane").hide();
    $("#step2").fadeIn(1000);
    $('.progressbar-dots').removeClass('active');
    $('.progressbar-dots:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
  }
});
$(".next-btn2").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    $(".tab-pane").hide();
    $("#step3").fadeIn(1000);
    $('.progressbar-dots').removeClass('active');
    $('.progressbar-dots:nth-child(3)').addClass('active');
  }
});

$(".submit-btn").click(function() {
  if (v.form()) {
    $("#loader").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#booking-form").html("<h2>Your message was sent successfully. Thanks! We'll be in touch as soon as we can, which is usually like lightning (Unless we're sailing or eating tacos!).</h2>");
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
});
```